# How to check health status of all services registered in Eureka server through Rest API instead of eureka dashboard?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, netflix-eureka

My requirement is I want to check the health status of all web services registered in my Eureka server through Rest API instead of the Eureka dashboard such as follows because one of my end applications wants to consume the health status of all web services registered in Eureka.

```
Health : {
 service-1 : UP,
 service-2 : UP,
 service-3 : DOWN,
}
```

Is there any way avavilable where we can call the eureka endpoint and receive health status in json format by calling the Eureka server endpoint

```
https://eureka-server.com/getHealth
```

should return registered service health status in JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the health information from the `/eureka/apps` API. The structure of this API is the following:

```json
{
  "applications": {
    "application": [{
      "name": "service-1",
      "instance": [{
        "hostName": "server-1",
        "app": "service-1",
        "status": "UP"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "service-2",
      "instance": [{
        "hostName": "server-1",
        "app": "service-2",
        "status": "DOWN"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

So, as you can see, the API returns a list of applications, and each application has a list of instances, which can have a status (eg. `"UP"`).

*Note (1): I left away some of the irrelevant data that the API returns for the sake of clarity.*

*Note (2): By default, the API returns the data in XML-format. If you prefer JSON, you can set the `Accept: application/json` header.*